# AFrame - Is it possible to replace the marker with a custom image without the black border?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, augmented-reality, aframe, jsartoolkit

I know we can generate a custom image using [this link](https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/three.js/examples/marker-training/examples/generator.html).

But the point is, I want a custom image that does not have any borders. With the link provided you can generate a custom image or `.patt` file with a black border around that image. It is applied to every image that is uploaded. The thing is, I want to use that image the way I want without the border as is shown. So my question is, is this possible in AFrame?

If not, please suggest me any other library or any other process that I can use to achieve this, if this is possible at all.

Comment: you could try vuforia, or a-frame argon,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Please look at @kalwalt's answer below. It is possible now.

currently it is not possible to use markers without border using jsartoolkit. There has been work to enable this. You can have a look here: https://github.com/artoolkitx/jsartoolkit5/tree/nft

However, that only performs on desktop not mobile.

Another way could be using OpenCV.js template matching: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dd1/tutorial_js_template_matching.html

cheers

Answer (score 0):

The **NFT** feature that [Thor_Bux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5843642/thor-bux) mentioned is merged on the master branch of [artoolkitx/jsartooolkit5](https://github.com/artoolkitx/jsartoolkit5/) and also in the new [AR.js](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js) repository. 
You can find the Ar.js documentation at:

https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/

Image Tracking (NFT):

https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/image-tracking/

Note that **Ar.js** is under a new github organization and any collaboration is very welcome.